# Error laravel tinker 5.4

Tags: laravel

I have error when update composer, please help me to fix it. Here is the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since Laravel v5.4 Tinker is a stand-alone package. You can install it with:

`composer require laravel/tinker`

You also need to add service provider in your `config/app.php` file:

`Laravel\Tinker\TinkerServiceProvider`